# Testing sessions in Vue.js and Node.js development environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

So the issue here i got is this: I am trying to use sessions for my app and while I know how to get them to work when everything is compiled and ready to go... I need to be able to test them during development.

So I have my Vue,js running on a different port than my node.js back end server. Wherein lies the problem; how to I get my back-end to use the address of my front end to be able to test this? For example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(session);
});
```

Would be localhost:5000/ (which is the port im using for now). I may be going about this the completely wrong way, but I'd like to be able to test this during the development rather than having to compile everything and pray that it works.

I am using express-sessions if it helps at all.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Okay so I'm trying proxies, and it doesnt seem to work. I tried putting it into the `package.json'file, then I read something on`vue.config.js` file where I Can do it this way.
So here is what I have:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:5000',
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `proxy` in `package.json` of your vue.js app. This way application will think that it is communicating with API on same server but in reality host of vue.js app will just be a proxy for your backend. My assumption is that backend app has prefix `api` for all of endpoint and that vue.js is hosted on Node.js server from npm scripts.

```
{
...
    "proxy": {
        "/api/*": {
          "target": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
     }
}
```

So when vue.js app tries to call `http://localhost:8080/api/hello` that request will go through proxy to `http://localhost:5000/api/hello`. Browser will allow that request.

Proxy is used only in development, in production is ignored.

## EDITED

If you are using new version of Vue CLI v3 you could use embedded proxy server: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

For an equivalent setup of the proxy, like presented above, create `vue.config.js` (if it doesn't exist already) with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I am curious though. The only address that will ever be used to the public will be: '/' and '/game' and I need sessions to reach any address. the home address i think isn't as detrimental as '/game' though. I guess ill just have to play around with it, thanks for your help again.

Comment: Hi @William I've added configuration for Vue CLI v3, if you are using new CLI.

Comment: I am using 2.5, but I think i need to upgrade it cause some of the information is confusing and changes. I figured it out, but I am still having trouble figuring some things out. Being new to using frameworks threw me for a bigger loops than I thought it would.